# Live HLS generator with iframe informatiom

Tags: video-streaming

I am trying to generate HLS live stream with Iframes support, for the trick mode support.
Please list some open source streaming engine.Already, tried with Wowza streaming engine.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for Wowza.

When you say you tried with Wowza, how did you try to configure this and what issues did you get?

Wowza allows you to create i-frame playlists for HLS, so curious what your experience was configuring that.

You can even use it with HLS adaptive-bitrate streaming. You add an I-frame only rendition to your SMIL file that will be used by the player for seeking. The I-frame rendition of your file has a `keyFrameOnly` parameter that must be set to TRUE.

```
<param name="<b>keyFrameOnly</b>" value="TRUE" valuetype="data"/>
```